# Error calling GetFilterVersion on Apache to Tomcat Redirector ISAPI Filter - 32bit W2K8 SP2 Standard

Tags: apache, tomcat, iis-7, isapi

I am getting an error trying to use the Apache ISAPI Redirector from IIS 7 to Tomcat but only on the 32 bit W2K8 SP2 Standard Edition.

It works fine on 64 bit W2K8 R2 and 32 bit W2K3.

I have verified that I have the correct 32 bit library (release 1.2.32 or 1.2.37). In fact the exact same library works on 32 bit W2K3. The filter is enabled and allowed and has permission to the library folder and registry entry.

When I rename the library, I get a different error: "Calling LoadLibraryEx on ISAPI Filter …. Failed" - Error Code 0x8007007e. I doesn't look like a permission issue.

The exact error text is "Calling GetFilterVersion on ISAPI Filter "….\isapi_redirector_1.0.dll" failed" - Error Code 0x80070002

The error log shows: The HTTP Filter DLL …\isapi_redirector_1.0.dll failed to load. Source=IIS-W3SVC-WP. The error code is 02 00 00 00

All pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: did you figured out the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple reasons for this. Some most common being:

1. Some dependencies are not being resolved for the 32-bit DLL. Open this DLL with Dependency walker and check for any errors in it (Skip the warnings in it). In most cases all dependent libraries are present, in such cases LoadLibraryEx error may come up because of the VC redistributables of specific version not present (If the DLL was built from VS 2010, the VC 2010 redistributables are needed).
2. Read permission for this DLL is not available to the application pool in which your website is running. Check properties of your website to see the user and make sure this user has permissions to the DLL.